# iframe src property as a URL dynamically Angular2

Tags: html, angular, iframe, ionic4

I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to dynamically change the URL in a iframe src.
I have tried setting the variables and then using string interpolation no luck.

Any suggestions on how i can do this. Possibly some examples if you could.

sample code i was trying;

```
src="https://www.wheehouse.org/company/PriceMin={{ this.itemMinimum }}&PriceMax={{ this.itemMaximum }}&BedRange={{ this.itemBedRoomType }}-0&BathRange={{ this.itemBathType }}-0"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1 - In HTML page - example string can be html, url, style, script etc

```js
[src] = "exampleString | safe: 'url'"
```

Step 2 - Create a safe pipe

Safe Pipe Code

```js
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeResourceUrl, SafeScript, SafeStyle, SafeUrl } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "safe" })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
        switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** - As per safe pipe is concerned you have to implement it in order to stop DOMSanitizer to strip out content from your URL.

Please check the below URL for how to implement safe pipe. [Link](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b)

Comment: thanks for your help and descriptive answer with Example. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Sushil have you implemented DOM Sanitizer using pipe?

Comment: You should not use method in your template, a [simple research](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=function+template+angular&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.4) on your navigator will let you understand why.

Comment: @Alexis I totally agree with you. It was initially written just for demo purpose. We can always directly bind string there. Thanks for pointing that out. I hope anyone using this example should keep that in mind while implementing. I am also adding a point regarding this in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Step 1 : Html file

```
<div *ngIf="softwareWorkingVideoLink">
    <iframe
      width="700"
      height="350"
      [src]="transform()"
      title="YouTube video player"
      frameborder="0"
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```

Step 2: .Ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { environment } from "../../../../environments/environment";
@Component({
  selector: "app-application-tour",
  templateUrl: "./application-tour.component.html",
})
export class ApplicationTourComponent {
  softwareWorkingVideoLink: string = environment.softwareWorkingVideoLink;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  transform() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      this.softwareWorkingVideoLink
    );
  }
}
```

Step 3 : environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  softwareWorkingVideoLink: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/JtvguK_hpIA",
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your properties are public in the component. then use the properties without `this` in the html

```
src="https://www.wheehouse.org/company/PriceMin={{ itemMinimum }}&PriceMax={{ itemMaximum }}&BedRange={{ itemBedRoomType }}-0&BathRange={{ itemBathType }}-0"
```

Comment: I tried that but i get the following error;
Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: Assign this to a variable and use it from html